# joining more tables makes me get less data from the query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, join

I have one problem with one SP, when I am joining some specific tables, I am getting less data from the SP then I am getting when they are not included in the SP. 
I am not getting any data from them yet, I am just joining them and only that makes the SP to send me less data.
Any idea what the problem can be? Thanks

Comment: You need to post the DDL for your tables and the stored procedure code in order for someone to be able to help. Also, which DB system are you using?

Comment: -1 for not providing more details.

Comment: @Unreason - how much more detail do you want? There are six answers - all of which are correct (or at least have correctly interpreted the question).

Comment: @Paul Spangle, I would expect to see the code of the SPs. That would have not been hard and I expect the OP to make some effort and leave less to the guessing game. But on the other hand you are right, the question got answered so I am removing my -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like there are no matching rows in the tables you're joining to.

If you change the join to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, you should get the rows you are expecting (but, obviously, check the output to make sure you do!)

Answer (score 1):

Joins usually have a join condition in the "ON" clause. That condition says how to match rows between the tables being joined. If, for a particular row on one side, there is no matching row on the other side, then we need to consider what type of join we're dealing with:

For an INNER JOIN, the row will be discarded.

For a LEFT JOIN, and if the row comes from the "LEFT" table source, then this row will appear, but with NULLs present for all columns from the "RIGHT" table source.

RIGHT JOIN is similar to left join, with the directions swapped over.

Answer (score 0):

regardless if you are asking for data from those tables or not, they have been included as part of the join, and the resultset is going to return rows that meet the criteria you have specified.

You may want to post 2 versions of the SP, one with few tables, then a second with one or more of the joins so that it can be better explained what is happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're doing an `INNER JOIN`. This will only return a record if whatever property you're joining on is in both tables. As an example:

```
Customers
ID    Name
1     Mike
2     Steve
3     Amy

Address
ID    Address
1     123 Main
3     456 Oak
```

If you

```
SELECT Name, Adddress FROM NAME N
   Join Address A ON N.Id = A.Id
```

Only The records for Mike and Amy will be returned because Steve doesn't have an Address record.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of join you are doing but it exists three kind of join

- INNER JOIN : Retrieves datas that matches on both side
- LEFT (OUTER) JOIN : Retrieves datas that only match on the left side, even if right is null
- RIGHT (OUTER) JOIN Retrieves datas that only mach on the right side, even if left is null

According to which one you are using, datas can be retrieved or not.

But posting your query will let us tell you what might be the real problem.

Hope I could help,

Answer (score 0):

See [this blog post by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).  It explains SQL Joins **very well**.  I think it will answer your question about why certain sets of data may or may not be missing.

Comment: The quality of the explanation is very questionable. The analogy used work only on joins that join on equality operator on unique columns (or set of unique columns). This is a special case of joins (although a very important one), but it does nothing to explain how number of rows can get multiplied if the join condition is true for a certain row multiple times.